# insert trigger to manipulate timestamps of existing rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, postgres-10, postgresql-triggers

I have a table with 2 date columns

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  code integer NOT NULL,
  eff_date timestamp default now(),
  exp_date timestamp default '2025-12-31'
);
```

I want to update the `exp_date` of an existing row when a new row with the same `code` is being inserted, the `exp_date` of the old row would be a day before the `eff_date` of the new row. Neither the `eff_date` or `exp_date` values would be in the insert query

For example:

| id | code | eff_date | exp_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 2021-01-31 | 2021-02-27 |
| 2 | 12345 | 2021-02-28 | 2021-03-30 |
| 3 | 12345 | 2021-03-31 | 2021-04-29 |
| 4 | 12345 | 2021-04-30 | 2021-05-30 |
| 5 | 12345 | 2021-05-31 | 2025-12-31 |

In this table, we want to update row with `id=1` when row `id=2` is being inserted by checking the **latest existing row** (with most recent `eff_date`) and updating it's `exp_date` to one day prior to `eff_date` of new row.

`exp_date` for `id=1` would become `2021-02-27` because `eff_date` of new row is `2021-02-28`.

Can this be done through an insert trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a trigger. `eff_date` and `exp_date` - although missing in the insert statement - will still be there with default values in the `new` record.

```sql
create or replace function test_insert_tf() returns trigger language plpgsql as 
$$
begin 
    update test 
    set exp_date = new.eff_date::date - 1 
    where code = new.code 
    and eff_date = (select max(eff_date) from test where code = new.code);
    return new;
end;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER test_insert_t
    before INSERT
    ON test
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_insert_tf();
```

Not very performant though. Btw is there a specific reason for `eff_date` and `exp_date` to be of type `timestamp`? Maybe type `date` would be more relevant.